# How can I use the Python language bindings for RPM / RPM5 on MacOS?

Tags: python, cross-platform, homebrew, rpm, rhel

On MacOS there is a [homebrew formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/rpm.rb) to install the RPM development package from [rpm5.org](http://rpm5.org/). However, this installs only the command line tools (rpm, rpmlint, rpmbuild, etc) and does not install any of the language bindings which are supported.

I would like to use the Pascal language bindings. However, when I build them and attempt to import the rpm package into Python 2.7 I get this error:

`$ python -c "import rpm._rpm"`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/venv-default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/**init**.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from _rpm import * ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/venv-default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/_rpmmodule.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension   Referenced
>   from: /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.15_1/lib/librpmio-5.4.dylib   Expected
>   in: flat namespace  in
>   /usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.15_1/lib/librpmio-5.4.dyl

To build the Python bindings I re-installed the rpm package with homebrew using these commands:

```
brew install -v --keep-tmp --build-from-source rpm 2>&1 | tee brew_install.log
cd /tmp/rpm-20170408-18245-1u8nsbs/rpm-5.4.15
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/rpm/5.4.15_1 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --with-path-cfg=/usr/local/etc/rpm --with-path-magic=/usr/local/share/misc/magic --with-path-sources=/usr/local/var/lib/rpmbuild --with-libiconv-prefix=/usr --disable-openmp --disable-nls --disable-dependency-tracking --with-db=external --with-sqlite=external --with-file=external --with-popt=external --with-beecrypt=internal --with-libtasn1=external --with-neon=internal --with-uuid=external --with-pcre=internal --with-lua=internal --with-syck=internal --without-apidocs varprefix=/usr/local/var --with-python
cd python
make
make install
```

Note the `./configure` command is the same one as Homebrew used with the `--with-python` switch appended.

How can I use the cross platform rpm5.org based source code to do Python language development on MacOS?

Comment: I don't think it's distributed separately at all.

Comment: `rpmlint` is not shipped as part of the rpm formula, it's a separate project.

Answer (score 1):

Your error depends on how sqlite3 and rpm are built on OS/X with brew.

sqlite3 can be built to add _sqlite3_enable_load_extension 
or RPM can be patched to remove the need for _sqlite3_enable_load_extension .

If patching RPM, see rpmio/rpmsql.c near line 2881.